# Find area of the largest possible triangle inscribed in the cardioid $r=1-\cos\theta$.

Tags: geometry, optimization, triangles, area

The best I can do is the triangle with vertices (in rectangular coordinates) $(0,1)$, $(0,-1)$ and $(-2,0)$. Can you do better or prove this yields maximal area?

I can show this is maximal for all triangles with either one vertex at $(0,0)$ or with one side that contains the point $(0,0)$.

Comment: @Mm393, the third vertex must be (2, 0).

Comment: Right, sorry!  I meant $1-\cos\theta$.

Comment: Yes, by "inscribed" I meant that the triangle must lie entirely inside the cardioid.  Complicates things, for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will be using the equivalent cardioid $r=1+\cos\theta$ for reasons to be made clear below. Using the Weierstrass rational representation $t=\tan\frac\theta2$, any point on the cardioid *but the cusp* (which is $t=\infty$; if I had used $r=1-\cos\theta$ the infinity point would be in the middle of a smooth curve, which I don't want) may be represented as
$$\frac2{1+t^2}\left(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)$$
Now take three parameters $t,u,v$ and define three points on the cardioid as above. The area of the triangle they define can be computed using the cross product and is the magnitude of
$$\frac{4(t-u)(u-v)(v-t)(tuv(t+u+v)+t^2+u^2+v^2+tu+uv+vt+3)}{((t^2+1)(u^2+1)(v^2+1))^2}$$
To maximise this area we simply take the derivative of this expression with respect to the three variables and solve for zero derivative (see Singular code below). There is an essentially unique solution
$$\{t,u,v\}=\{-x,0,x\}\qquad x=\sqrt{\frac{2\sqrt{13}-5}3};\ 3x^4+10x^2-9=0\tag1$$
which produces a triangle wholly in the cardioid whose area is *larger* than that of the triangle you found:
$$\sqrt{\frac{945+351\sqrt{13}}{128}}=4.155708\ldots>4$$
Since I introduced no other constraints and you've handled the case where the triangle hits the cusp, the maximum area triangle in the cardioid is described by $(1)$ and depicted below.

[image]

**How to find the solution**

```
option(prot); LIB "elim.lib";
ring r=0,(t,u,v),dp;
poly up=4*(t-u)*(u-v)*(v-t)*(tuv*(t+u+v)+t2+u2+v2+tu+uv+vt+3);
poly down=((t2+1)*(u2+1)*(v2+1))^2;
poly p1=diff(up,t)*down-up*diff(down,t);
poly p2=diff(up,u)*down-up*diff(down,u);
poly p3=diff(up,v)*down-up*diff(down,v);
p1=p1/((u-v)*(t2+1)*(u2+1)^2*(v2+1)^2);
p2=p2/((v-t)*(t2+1)^2*(u2+1)*(v2+1)^2);
p3=p3/((t-u)*(t2+1)^2*(u2+1)^2*(v2+1));
poly q1=resultant(p1,p2,v)/((t-u)^3*(t2+1)^2*(u2+1)^2);
poly q2=resultant(p1,p3,v)/((t-u)*(t2+1)^4*(u2+1)^2);
poly p4=product(factorize(resultant(q1,q2,u),1))/((t2+1)*(t2+9));
ideal I=p1,p2,p3,p4;
ring rr=0,(t,u,v),lp;
ideal J=imap(r,I);
triangL(stdfglm(J));
```

The above Singular code first constructs denominator-removed expressions for the derivatives of the triangle area with respect to the three variables, then uses resultants to derive a polynomial for $t$; this fourth polynomial is required to make the ideal zero-dimensional. Finally the triangular systems combining to make this ideal are computed, yielding this result:

```
[1]:
   _[1]=v2-3
   _[2]=u2-3
   _[3]=t2-3
[2]:
   _[1]=v
   _[2]=3u5+10u3-9u
   _[3]=t+u
[3]:
   _[1]=3v4+10v2-9
   _[2]=u3-uv2
   _[3]=6t-3u2v3-10u2v-3u+6v
[4]:
   _[1]=640108624098375v36-5148337921041000v34+26978868204221536v32-90595830671241144v30+174477817769250492v28-88887184063433688v26-264130789939546320v24+211247992383077736v22+629579509772920194v20-489083285277323208v18-795841216135748160v16-175972388059888936v14+40854222661032492v12+7808458598580024v10-1155576993811920v8-75113448395400v6+15409537814223v4-613666496304v2+3673320192
   _[2]=u-v
   _[3]=t-v
[5]:
   _[1]=v4+2v2+1
   _[2]=u-v3-2v
   _[3]=1920325872295125t43-14804905139024625t41+50824030351786983t39-26740512038246771t37-758343361196236572t35+4169483103271335516t33-10132001875006352724t31+8547114445453364004t29+10001133359631435222t27-16207873377366831774t25-21726512020485356382t23+34749136509369035382t21+17779149006729660164t19-14560510102872759252t17-6340227433780124196t15+797153209164258228t13+255867000085372797t11-28257585807175929t9-2629637727966225t7+439994187660069t5-16712254887696t3+99179645184t
```

Solutions $1,4,5$ are rejected because they either involve complex numbers or degenerate the triangle. Solutions $2$ and $3$ are equivalent after allowing for variable permutations and removing more degeneracies; they correspond to $(1)$ above. All throughout the Singular code, extraneous factors are removed to keep the running time low.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!  Would you happen to know offhand the measures of the angles of this maximal triangle?  Seems there should be a less algebra-heavy solution, too, but this is great!

Comment: @MM393 The angle at $(2,0)$ has a cosine of $\frac{27-7\sqrt{13}}4$. The triangle is isoceles and that angle is the unique one, so you should be able to work out the other angles.

Comment: Given the “weirdness” of the solution triangle (roughly a 64-58-58 triangle), I take back what I said about a less algebra-heavy solution!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use herons formula, which gives the area of a triangle as:
$$A=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$$
where:
$$s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$$
If we represent the vertices as vectors $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ then the lengths are just:
$$a=|\alpha-\beta|$$
$$b=|\beta-\gamma|$$
$$c=|\gamma-\alpha|$$

Comment: I have considered that approach.  The calculations get quite onerous, though (maybe I'm not persistent enough!).  One difficulty is that all three sides must lie entirely inside the cardioid.

Comment: I'm not sure if this makes things easier, but you can use your triangle to split the cardioid up into pieces and find the area of these, combining them and working out the triangles proportion of the total area will give you a "packing factor"

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution is perfectly correct, but I'm still bothered by the "algebraic intensity" of it.

If (and this may be a big "if") one can first argue that the triangle of maximum area must be isosceles and symmetric about the $x$-axis, then there are two (easy-ish) cases:

**Case 1:** One vertex is at the origin.

Then we need to maximize the function $A(x)=-\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos x)^2\sin(2x)$ on the interval $(\pi/2,\pi)$.  This function is maximized at $x=\frac{4\pi}{5}$, with maximum value of about 1.556. (This case can be done by hand.)

**Case 2:** One vertex is at the point $(-2,0)$.

Then we need to maximize the function $A(x)=(2-\cos x(\cos x-1))(1-\cos x)\sin x$ on the interval $[\pi/2,\pi)$.  This function is maximized (with help from Wolfram|Alpha) at $x\approx1.723$ (roughly $98.7^\circ$), with maximum value of about 2.078.

In both cases, $x$ is the angle between the positive $x$-axis and the ray with initial point $(0,0)$ passing through a vertex of the triangle (other than $(0,0)$ or $(-2,0)$, as the case may be).